# How to start Tomcat 7 from Windows command line in the same window?

Tags: command-line, windows-7, tomcat7

When I run `%TOMCAT_ROOT%\bin\startup.bat` from a `Windows 7` command line, it opens a new window with default command line window settings (I have them personalized). I would prefer to run it in the same command window in the same prompt and not forked off in a separate window.

[image]

As you can see, the inner Tomcat window in the picture above is smaller and has a smaller font. I would like to run the server in the bigger, parent window where I executed `startup.bash`.

Essentially, I would like to run it on Windows the same way it would run as a console Linux application if I ran `startup.sh`.

Comment: OK -- is it possible to display the server trace in the same parent window, like it would if I ran it on a Linux server ? I thought there should be some option that does that.

Comment: You can use `Catalina start`, use `catalina jpda start` if you want to start tomcat with debug mode.

Comment: I did `catalina.bat start` but that opened a new window also.  i am basically looking for how to reverse engineer the java executable that the exe invokes in a new window so i can run it from my window

Comment: figured it out. please see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to run it in the same window using

> catalina.bat run

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
catalina.bat run
```

This will do the trick. However the reason why it works lies within the file catalina.bat(for windows)/catalina.sh(for linux). Check how the action run and start blocks(:doRun and :doStart) are implemented. Both of them will start the tomcat; `run` in foreground and `start` in the background.